# Find redundant function calls within call tree?

Tags: c, static-analysis

I have a function which I believe is called multiple times in the same code path - like `c()` in the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147758/detecting-redundant-function-calls-within-call-stack-tree-with-dtrace).  Is there any way to statically find what code paths call `c()`, and to see if any of those paths lead to redundant calls?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how static analysis could solve this except for very simple cases.

Comment: That first line seems like an open invitation to get your question closed as a dupe. Rather than pointing to some other question, you should clearly state what you're asking.

Comment: @Caleb - I thought that graphic in the linked question was the best explanation for my problem, but you're right I should have provided more here.  Edited.

Comment: @PeterG. - Well, with ncc and CodeViz I can generate some nice function call graphs.  For simple cases it's easy to visually inspect the graph and find redundancies, but I figured it might be possible for a tool to do that automatically, and perhaps for cases that are a bit too complicated for manual inspection.  But maybe not, I don't know.